# How to carry out equations on multiple fractions

Tags: java, math

I have written some basic code to calculate mathematical expression using two fractions but I am stumped on how to carry out a calculation on more than this e.g.`1/2 + 1/2 * 1/2`

My code for two fractions is below. Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Evaluate {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your equation, please seperate fractions and operators with a space: ");

        String[] equation = in.nextLine().split(" ");

        String a = equation[0];
        String a2 = equation[2];
        String a4 = equation[1];

        String[] a1 = a.split("/");
        String[] a3 = a2.split("/");

        int b = Integer.parseInt(a1[0]);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(a1[1]);

        int b1 = Integer.parseInt(a3[0]);
        int c1 = Integer.parseInt(a3[1]);

        Fraction first = new Fraction(b,c);
        Fraction second = new Fraction(b1,c1);

        if(a4.equals("*")){
            Fraction multi = first.multiply(second);
                System.out.println(multi);
        }
        else if(a4.equals("+")){
            Fraction add = first.add(second);
            System.out.println(add);
        }
        else if(a4.equals("-")){
            Fraction sub = first.subtract(second);
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
        else if(a4.equals("/")){
            Fraction div = first.divideBy(second);
            System.out.println(div);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: If you want more than 2 inputs, the first step is to rewrite your code so that you can accept "any number of inputs". Simply expanding from 2 to 3 is just going to make the code less and less maintainable. Aggregate the inputs in a list, and then resolve the list once the user is done inputting data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. Sorry but I don't understand. Can you give me a clue to get me started?

Comment: Be very careful.  You need to ensure that you're using floating-point values when you divide, or you will run into integer division problems (truncating the decimal part).

Comment: You need to write a Java class Rational or Fraction that encapsulates all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting your string by spaces is adequate, and should work with multiple operators:

```
String[]  equation = in.nextLine.split(" ");
```

Now that you have that, you want to iterate over that and create two ArrayLists, one for your operators, and one for your fractions of the form `x/y`:

```
String[] operators = new String[equation.length/2];
String[] fractions = new String[operators.length+1];
for (int i = 0; i < equation.length; i+=2)
{
    fractions[i] = equation[i];
    operators[i] = equation[i+1];
}
```

Now you have 2 ArrayLists with all the stuff you need, just iterate over those:

```
Fraction[] newFractions = new Fraction[fractions.length];
for (int i = 0; i < fractions.length; i++)
    String[] parts = fractions[i].split("/");
    Fraction[i] = new Fraction(parts[0],parts[1]);
```

Then go over the operators ArrayList and do those:

```
for (int i = 0; i < operators.length; i++)
{
    if (operators[i] == "*")
        //Multiply your fractions
        //Something like this, I haven't used the Fraction class before, nor heard of it
        //Shouldn't throw out of bounds because the size should be 1 bigger
        newFractions[i+1] = newFractions[i].multiply(newFractions[i+1]);
    else if (operators[i] == "+")
        //Add your fractions
    else if (operators[i] == "-")
        //Subtract your fractions
    else if (operators[i] == "/")
        //Divide your fractions
}
```

Comment: @Gangadi Edited to use Arrays instead of ArrayLists

Answer (score -1):

You can use `javascript engine` in `java` to evaluate the infix expression. For that import

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
```

and then do the following:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String equation = "1/2 + 1/2 * 1/2";
System.out.println(engine.eval(equation));
```

Comment: Thanks Johny but unfortunately can't use any libraries or scripts